# IE 9-11 issue of font-face with query string

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, version, font-face

To avoid browser's cache, I concat version querystring to the font-face just like FontAwesome does as below.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

This works fine on most browsers, even on IE 7/8. But on IE 9/10/11, the browser sends the request URL like ".../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?" without the version string. This results in no update on the font file and still using the old version.

I searched StackOverflow and google, but cannot find anything about this problem. I'd appreciate it if anyone can help.

I know I can change the font path to the one like "../fonts/4.7.0/fontawesome-webfont.eot" to solve this problem, but this is not convenient as the former.

Comment: As an alternative approach for preventing browser caching, I suggest you add `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache"> <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">` to the `<head>` part of your HTML code and make a test with the IE browser to see whether it can give you the desired result.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, thanks, but I need the browser caching to prevent from re-fetching these asset files frequently. Otherwise the web loading speed might not be good. Actually I set the max-age to 1 year. I use the query string to do a version control. This should work and Font-Awesome or bootstrap also use this way. Only IE 9/10/11 has the problem.

Comment: At present, I did not get any other solution for the said issue, If possible you can try to make a test with the latest Microsoft Edge browser. I may help to avoid the issue.

Comment: As I described, I only see the problem on IE 9~11, chrome, firefox and edge have no such problem. Anyway, I now use the way like "../font/4.7.0/xxx.eot" to solve this problem, instead of using a query string to the url. Thanks.